# Using perl to split over multiple lines

Tags: perl, split

I'm trying to write a perl script to process a log4net log file. The fields in the log file are separated by a semi-colon. My end goal is to capture each field and populate a mysql table.

Usually I have lines that look a little like this (all on a single line)

```
DEBUG;2017-06-13T03:56:38,316-05:00;2017-06-13 08:56:38,316;79ab0b95-7f58-
44a8-a2c6-1f8feba1d72d;(null);WorkerStartup 1;"Starting services."
```

These are easy to process. I can simply split by semicolon to get the information I need.

However occassionally the "message" field at the end may span several lines, especially if there is a stack trace. I would want to capture the entire message as a single column. I cannot use split by semicolon, because the next lines would typically look like:

```
 at some.random.classname
 at another.classname
 ...
```

Can someone give some tips how to solve this problem?

Comment: Look for a delimiter, and set `$/`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You know how to identify the *start* of a log entry. Use that information to accumulate subsequent lines until you hit another log entry.

Comment: You can read all about the magic variable `$/` (input record separator) [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses that the number of " in a field is even `($p=~y/"//%2)`, this condition number of `"` odd may be changed by other that can indicate the field is not complete.
The number of columns splitted is fixed to `7` (to allow `;` in last field) and may be changed for example `@array = map {s/;$//} $p=~/\G(?:"[^"]*"|[^;])*;/g;`.
The file is read line by line but a line is processed `sub process` when it's complete `$p` variable to store the previous line the last line is processed in END block.

```
perl -ne '
    sub process {
        @array = split /;/,$p,7;
        # do something with array
        print ((join "\n---\n", @array),"\n");
    }
    if ($p=~y/"//%2) {
        $p.=$_;
        next;
    }
    process;
    $p=$_;
    END{process}
' < logfile.txt
```